A Hat Guessing Problem without Much Meta Knowledge
Three perfect logicians are seated such that they can all see one-another. They each have a hat with a non-negative integer on it. It is known that the number on one of the hats is the sum of the numbers on the two others.
The three logicians make the following statements, in order:
Logician A says: "I know the number on my hat."
Logician B says: "I know the number on my hat."
Logician C says: "I know the number on my hat."
What are their numbers, and how did they know?

Hint: An exchange in the comments (now deleted), is on the path toward a solution. Paraphrased below in spoilers:

 Q: Wouldn't any triple where $B=C$ and $A$ is the sum work here?
 A: This would be true if the numbers were guaranteed to be positive, but they only need to be non-negative. $B=C$ in this case does not allow the first logician to immediately know their number, since their number could be either $2*B$ or zero.


Sorry for being dense, but how is this not just [0, 0, 0]? Your comment implies they don't need to be unique and that multiple hats are allowed to be the sum.

@LukasRotter - If you believe you have an answer, you should post it as an answer and not a comment.


We can conclude that one of B or C has 0 as their number


Assume both B and C have positive integers. A knows that either A = B + C, B = A + C or C = A + B. When B >= C we can also discount that third equation, and when B < C we can discount the second. In any case, A is stuck with two possibilities for their number. However, when at least one of B or C is 0 both possibilities reduce to A = B (or A = C when C is the non-zero number). Thus A is able to deduce their number from only B and C's hats.


Once A has stated their number it's trivial for B and C to deduce their own. Either B sees that C has a zero, in which case they know B = A, or they see C has a non-zero number, in which case they know B = 0. Likewise for C.


Well solved! I actually made a mistake when posing this question - I believed that [0,0,0] was the only solution (which is why the question asks "What are their numbers" instead of "what do we know about their numbers?", but as you've noted, there are other solutions. Knowing that now, this problem would be better if Logician 3 said something like, "My number is 1" instead.
